# Is my task force tag bugged or is this display showing something else?

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

In Ghost Recon Wildlands, up by my gamertag and gamer avatar icon, a small bracket is showing `[55650]`, see the attached screenshot:

[image: Ghost Recon Wildlands screenshot]

This is on Xbox One, and when I check my [Ghost Recon Network](https://ghostreconnetwork.ubi.com/) task force settings I can see that my task force is named "XboxKlubben" (Norwegian name), with the tag "[XbK]":

[image: Task Force Settings]

I thought the text in bracket inside the game was supposed to show the tag of my task force but clearly it does not. Is this just bugged? Is there a way to refresh the task force tag on Xbox One for Wildlands?

I have a PC copy of Wildlands as well but on this it shows the correct tag, and I've double and triple checked that I'm looking at the Xbox One task force on the website.

Note that people I play with also see the number, in angle brackets beside my game, such as `<55650> LasseVK`. I don't have a screenshot of this however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely a bug.  If you go to your Task Force's [home page](https://ghostreconnetwork.ubi.com/en-US/task-force/profile/55650/XboxKlubben), the URL is:

`https://ghostreconnetwork.ubi.com/en-US/task-force/profile/55650/XboxKlubben`

Notice that the number after `profile/` is 55650, the same number you are seeing in the brackets.  If I had to guess, the Xbox version of the game may be interpreting the code differently or incorrectly, and thus is pulling the number of your Task Force and not the name.

I've also found a [GameFAQs post](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168640-tom-clancys-ghost-recon-wildlands/75096813) of someone experiencing the same issue as well as an [Ubisoft Page](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/1599560-GRN-task-force).

Comment: This makes sense. I'll try to contact support then.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen that number is likely the task force ID number in their records if I had to guess.